# How do i use a checkbox in HTA to where if checked it will run a section of vbscript?

Tags: html, checkbox, vbscript, hta

i'm wondering if someone can help me...

I have a section of code in which i am using HTA as a GUI to define all variables and then run a number of subroutines based on the answers provided in the GUI.

I have managed to get the text based values to be input and run the "ValidateSelectionCreateFolders" subroutine. I am now wanting to use checkboxes to decide whether or not to run other subroutines, i've included a sample of my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Market Risk BAU Reporting</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION
APPLICATIONNAME="Market Risk BAU Reporting"
ID="MRiskBAUReport"
VERSION="1.0"
SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
SCROLL="no"/>


<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #DCDCDC;
color: #192272;
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 12pt;
margin: 4em 3em;
}
</style>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">

Sub ValidateSelectionCreateFolders()
'Other Code Here
End Sub 

Sub ProcessGapRun()
LogFile.WriteLine(Now() & " ProcessGapRunning")
End Sub

Sub RunReportingCycle ()

ValidateSelectionCreateFolders

If ProcessGap.Checked Then
    ProcessGapRun
  Else
    MsgBox "ProcessGap is Unchecked"
  End if

End Sub

<body>
<FORM name="RunSettings">
<p>Staff ID: <input name="StaffID" type="text"></P>
<p>Current Portfolio Date: <input name="InputPortfolio" type="text"></P>
<p>Current Market Date: <input name="InputMarket" type="text"></P>
<p>Previous Portfolio Date: <input name="InputPrevPortfolio" type="text"></P>
<p>2nd Previous Portfolio Date: <input name="InputPrev2Portfolio" type="text"></P>
Which processes do you want to run?
<p>Process Gap Report <input name="ProcessGap" type="checkbox" id="ProcessGap"></P>
<p>Export Gap Report <input name="ExportGap" type="checkbox" id="ExportGap"></P>
<p>Process EuroGap Report <input name="ProcessEURGap" type="checkbox" id="ProcessEURGap"></P>
<p>Export EuroGap Report <input name="ExportEURGap" type="checkbox" id="ExportEURGap"></P>
<p>Process Basis Risk Report <input name="ProcessBasis" type="checkbox" id="ProcessBasis"></P>
<p>Export Basis Risk Report <input name="ExportBasis" type="checkbox" id="ExportBasis"></P>

<input type="button" value="Confirm Above Selection" onclick="RunReportingCycle" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

If i have checked the checkbox when i press the button i want it to first run the code that works already 'ValidateSelectionCreateFolders' and then know that the checkbox is checked and so run another subroutine 'ProcessGapRun'.
I would really appreciate any help as my current code just keeps falling down with the error **Object required: 'ProcessGap'**

I then intend to add a number of additional checkboxes that will then run other code, but i will want it to happen individually as each checkbox is dependent upon the previous being run, how could i do this?

Thanks

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it.

```
<script language="VBScript">
Sub ValidateSelectionCreateFolders()
  MsgBox "ValidateSelectionCreateFolders() runs"
End Sub 

Sub ProcessGapRun()
  MsgBox "ProcessGapRun() runs"
End Sub

Sub RunReportingCycle ()
  ValidateSelectionCreateFolders
  If Document.all.ProcessGap.Checked Then
    ProcessGapRun
  Else
    MsgBox "ProcessGap is Unchecked"
  End if
End Sub
</script>
```

HTML elements that have an ID are available in the `Document.all` collection.

---

By the way, you can combine JavaScript and VBScript code in HTAs. Maybe you want to write at least part of the code in a language that works better with web pages  and has more examples available (you can even use jQuery):

```html
<!-- add JSON and jQuery support -->
<script language="JScript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20160511/json2.min.js"></script>
<script language="JScript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="VBScript">
  ' VBScript functions ...
</script>

<script language="JScript">
$(function () {
  $("#btnConfirm").click(function () {       // use jQuery
    ValidateSelectionCreateFolders();        // call VBScript function from JS
    if ($("#ProcessGap").is(":checked")) {   
      ProcessGapRun();
    } else {
      alert("ProcessGap is Unchecked");
    }
  });
});
</script>

<!-- ... other HTML elements -->

<input id="btnConfirm" type="button" value="Confirm Above Selection" /></p>
```